# Jsoup Java doc.select Yahoo Finance

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, yahoo-finance

I understand the Jsoup code to retrieve "Stock Name" and "Current Stock Price" from a Yahoo Finance page (e.g. http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=goog):

```
String price = doc.select(".time_rtq_ticker").first().text();
String name = doc.select(".title h2").first().text();
```

But I am not sure how to select other data, for example the **Open:** or **Volume:** values.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Elements open = doc.getElementsByTag("Open");
Elements volume = doc.getElementsByTag("Volume");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all of the data from the table and then get the correct indexes as separate Elements:

```
Elements e = doc.select("td.yfnc_tabledata1");
Element open = e.get(1);   // index for open is 1
Element volume = e.get(9); // index for volume is 9

System.out.println("Open: " + open.text());
System.out.println("Volume: " + volume.text());
```

Will output:

```
Open: 1,037.16
Volume: 1,613,009
```

You can't use `getElementsByTag("Open")` or `getElementsByTag("Volume")` because those tags don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure it return right result but data will contain in :

```
doc.select("span.time_rtq_ticker");
```